# Got random branches on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

I created a private project on gitlab with the main branch master. As you can see in the image, I have a lot of other random branches that I haven't created at all and don't know where they are coming from. Could you help me and tell me, how can I delete them?

[image: Git error]

Comment: Did you create the project using sample-gitlab-project (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/sample-data-templates/sample-gitlab-project/-/branches?state=all&sort=name_asc) as a template?

Comment: yes, is there a way to delete them?

Comment: Although you *can* continue by deleting all the branches, if it were me, I would create a new blank repo to do real work in. Perhaps you can keep a copy of the example repo for playing around and learning.

Comment: Note: these are technically *remote-tracking names* (Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, using the word *branch* pointlessly here), so they aren't actually *branch* names. The point of a remote-tracking name is to have your own clone remember some other Git repository's branch names: these are reflections of the fact that the *GitLab* repo has these as branch names.

Comment: Once you've cleaned up the names in the GitLab copy, use `git fetch --prune` if necessary to instruction your Git software to delete stale remote-tracking names. You can set up your Git software to prune by default, so that you don't have to remember this step.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository has these branches because you created it using the [Sample GitLab Project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/sample-data-templates/sample-gitlab-project) as a template. You can delete the branches in the same way you would delete branches in any other repository:

1. Use the GitLab UI - go to https://gitlab.com/your-username/your-repo-name/-/branches and use the "Delete branch" button to delete each of them in turn
2. Use git on the command line: `git push origin --delete <branch-name>`

As there are quite a few branches in the sample project, you may want to use this command to delete them all in one go (this assumes you haven't pushed any commits to any of them):

```
git push origin --delete \
at-adipisci-ducimus-qui-nihil \
atque-corrupti-laboriosam-nobis-explicabo \
aut-deleniti-est-voluptatum-repellat \
autem-at-dolore-molestiae-et \
autem-vitae-sequi-commodi-velit \
cumque-occaecati-veniam-qui-sit \
dolorem-ratione-sed-illum-minima \
dolores-sit-quos-explicabo-ut \
doloribus-dolorem-quos-adipisci-et \
ea-dolor-quia-et-sint \
et-laudantium-voluptas-quos-pariatur \
et-non-impedit-praesentium-ex \
et-recusandae-deleniti-voluptas-consectetur \
fugiat-libero-sit-magnam-ad \
inventore-temporibus-ipsum-neque-rerum \
ipsum-consequatur-et-in-et \
iste-consequatur-dolor-odio-dolorum \
laudantium-unde-et-iste-et \
modi-et-quam-sunt-consequatur \
natus-autem-dolores-incidunt-nostrum \
nostrum-ut-vel-voluptates-et \
possimus-pariatur-autem-magni-animi \
qui-in-quod-nam-voluptatem \
qui-quidem-animi-inventore-in \
quisquam-dolorum-minus-non-ipsam \
recusandae-ex-ipsam-libero-fugit \
sapiente-et-possimus-neque-est \
sed-sit-tempore-expedita-possimus \
voluptatem-quas-error-et-molestiae \
voluptatem-quia-fugit-ut-perferendis
```